# how to use setTimeout on a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a typing effect using javascript however the text is not readable because it's too fast. I really need a way to make my function pause in every sentence.

```js
const texts = ["get a quote", "get a Tweet"];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = "";
let letter = "";

function type() {
  if (count === texts.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  currentText = texts[count];
  letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);

  document.getElementById("welcome").textContent = letter;
  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
    count++;
    index = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(type, 100)

};
type()
```

```html
<div id="welcome"></div>
```

Comment: Introduce another `setTimeout` for between sentences.

Comment: And just to be precise: You can't really "pause" a function in JS (except generators). Your function simply schedules some instructions to be executed some time in the future. The function itself will run and terminate normally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a variable for the delay and use a larger one when changing sentences

```js
const texts = ["get a quote", "get a Tweet"];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = "";
let letter = "";

function type() {
  let delay = 100; // default delay between typing chars
  if (count === texts.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  currentText = texts[count];
  letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);

  document.getElementById("welcome").textContent = letter;
  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
    count++;
    index = 0;
    delay = 1000; // larger delay between sentences
  }

  setTimeout(type, delay); // use the delay variable here instead of hardcoding a value

};
type()
```

```html
<div id="welcome"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this instead, it gives a different delay to the setTimeout function in the case of a new sentence:

```
      const texts = ["get a quote", "get a Tweet"];
      let count = 0;
      let index = 0;
      let currentText = "";
      let letter = "";

      function type() {
        if (count === texts.length) {
          count = 0;
        }
        currentText = texts[count];
        letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);

        document.getElementById("welcome").textContent = letter;
        if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
          count++;
          index = 0;
          setTimeout(type, 1000);
        } else {
          setTimeout(type, 100);
        }
      }
      type();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code that doesn't require any global variables, and introduces a two second pause between each line of text.

It uses a loop to extract the first letter of each sentence, adds that to the element textContent, and then passes the remaining letters back to the function using a setTimeout. If there are no letters left in the sentence, another setTimeout is called after two seconds, resetting the textContent, and then calling the loop again with the next sentence in the array.

```js
const texts = ["get a quote", "get a Tweet"];
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function type(texts) {

  // The index initially points to the
  // first array element
  let index = 0;

  function loop(str) {

    // If the string still has letters
    if (str.length) {

      // Destructure the first letter from it
      // add assign all the other letters to `rest`
      const [ letter, ...rest ] = str;

      // Add the letter to the textContent
      div.textContent += letter;
      
      // Then call the function again with the
      // rest of the letters
      setTimeout(loop, 100, rest);

    // If there are no letters left increase the index,
    // check to see if the array has that index,
    // then, after two seconds, reset the textContent
    // and call the function again with a fresh sentence
    } else {
      ++index;
      if (index < texts.length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          div.textContent = '';
          loop(texts[index]);
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }

  loop(texts[0]);

}

type(texts);
```

```html
<div id="welcome"></div>
```